# GWT Training for JAVA Developer

Tags: gwt

Can anyone recommend books and/or online training options for GWT?  Preferably for cheap as I will be footing this bill myself

Answer (score 3):

Check a lot of useful [videos about GWT on **Best Tech Videos**](http://www.bestechvideos.com/search?query=GWT) and the [**Google Tutorials on GWT**](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/index.html)

A list of other resources:

- [GWT tutorial](http://www.softwaredesign.co.uk/gwt.html)
- [Introduction Tutorial on Google Web Toolkit (Video)](http://technofriends.in/2009/06/10/video-introduction-tutorial-on-google-web-toolkit/)
- [36 GWT Tutorials](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2007/07/36-gwt-tutorial/)
- [Google Web Toolkit (GWT) Resource Center](http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Web20/GoogleWebToolkitGWT/GoogleWebToolkitTutorialsandDemos/tabid/1327/Default.aspx)

Google provides a **list of [books](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/books.html)** that have been published regarding GWT, including a short description of each.

Comment: Note: As of 2014-09-12, _questions_ asking for recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you would like to _ensure_ your answer lives on for posterity, consider whether any of it could fit [in a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 1):

Have you walked through their [tutorials](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

- [GWT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html)
- [free book](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this website:
[GWT 2.8.1 Declarative User Interface Web Application Development](http://millionstrengthknowledge.com/gwt281training.html)

Sample chapter:

(1) [Develop HTML Page using GWT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMLRrDXdOk0)

(2) [TabLayoutPanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fwvCa7rRto)